# VS2019 - User Control - The Designer Cannot Be Shown for Imported User Control

Tags: vb.net, winforms, inheritance, user-controls, visual-studio-2019

This is happening only now that we have migrated to Visual Studio 2019.  This is in Win Forms, VB.NET.

We have a Control (**baseControl**) which inherits User Control in Project A.
We then have a Control (**newControl**) which inherits **baseControl**.

All good in Project A.

When *both* **baseControl** and **newControl** are imported to Project B:

- **baseControl** can be designed; no problem.
- **newControl** cannot be designed.  The following Call Stack is shown:

> at
> System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager
> manager) at
> System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
> manager) at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
> serializationManager)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
> serializationManager) at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32
> fReload)

"Import" means:  Right-click the Project, and select "Add" → "Existing Item..."
Then, select:

- baseControl.vb
- baseControl.resx
- newControl.vb
- newControl.resx

Most confusing is that baseControl *can* be designed in Project B, while the Class / Control inheriting it cannot.

This did not happen while still using Visual Studio 2010.

All assistance appreciated.

Comment: Did you copy/import the baseControl.Designer.vb and newControl.Designer.vb ?

Comment: When you import a User Control or a Form, you usually select just the main class for import (e.g., `baseControl.vb`), not all files. Do that one at the time. VS will recreate the whole class (it may take a few seconds for the usual icon associated with a class which has Designer to shown up) -- Selecting all files can make a mess. More messy if you miss the Designer file (e.g., `baseControl.Designer.vb`), so I'm quite surprised one of those actually works.

Comment: @Jimi - Your comment here got me on the right path.
I performed the following in the 2nd Project:
1. Deleted the Base Control (which the subsequent User Controls inherited)
2. Add ... Existing Item ... And selected ONLY the .VB file of the Base Control
This 'fixed' the Controls inheriting the Base Control.
I had originally selected both the .vb and .resx items when performing the Add Existing Item.  Thank you both for your responses.  I'll test again to be sure the sequence of events is stated accurately here, and then close the Question.

Comment: Just to add more context, we never had a problem with this in older versions of VS.  But we skipped from 2010 to 2019.